# Action not being set in url

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core, routes

So i'm trying to get create password recovery with .net identity.
I'm using the default angular implementation which visual studio generates for you, so routing is set up for both angular and mvc.

I can generate some url that contains the userid and token and put them into variables. But when i try to access the page with the variables it will not load and just defaults to the angular homepage.

So this:

```
http://localhost:5062/changepassword?userid=07a5646-243a-44b3-8281-7af3a43ab3&token=CfDJ8IZmdPTj9sJNgJNVd5zgrmN+YMg2B+phPe3Yaw4K/5qDMmjwaRtY7nEt79P14XEvuez86enX2fSw/WIKRIgqt2u58S+xSG+rHKVx65iHjQIMEs59LfeXkichbC4zmY7YLqZw9AZrDxFUtsjZZx5SsVQKBphNWWOxjYYJ1CV/MVtxuQOiLEd6BhbAeWhzt8Snd0aEMouS9eMCi7KN/r7MPCmFgr2VSk09UJKRFW30+SxH4miDNG1CVPfoEzFyRw==
```

changes to this when i try to go to the above link:

```
http://localhost:5062/home?userid=07a5646-243a-44b3-8281-7af3a43ab3&token=CfDJ8IZmdPTj9sJNgJNVd5zgrmN+YMg2B+phPe3Yaw4K/5qDMmjwaRtY7nEt79P14XEvuez86enX2fSw/WIKRIgqt2u58S+xSG+rHKVx65iHjQIMEs59LfeXkichbC4zmY7YLqZw9AZrDxFUtsjZZx5SsVQKBphNWWOxjYYJ1CV/MVtxuQOiLEd6BhbAeWhzt8Snd0aEMouS9eMCi7KN/r7MPCmFgr2VSk09UJKRFW30+SxH4miDNG1CVPfoEzFyRw==
```

My angular routing line looks like this:

```
{ path: 'changepassword/:userid/:token', component: ChangePasswordComponent },
```

I looked up some stuff about angular routing with variables and they state different things and i am really lost in what the correct way to do this is.
Some say i don't need to declare the variables in the angular routing, and some say the link should look like this:

```
http://localhost:5062/changepassword;userid=07a5646-243a-44b3-8281-7af3a43ab3;token=CfDJ8IZmdPTj9sJNgJNVd5zgrmN+YMg2B+phPe3Yaw4K/5qDMmjwaRtY7nEt79P14XEvuez86enX2fSw/WIKRIgqt2u58S+xSG+rHKVx65iHjQIMEs59LfeXkichbC4zmY7YLqZw9AZrDxFUtsjZZx5SsVQKBphNWWOxjYYJ1CV/MVtxuQOiLEd6BhbAeWhzt8Snd0aEMouS9eMCi7KN/r7MPCmFgr2VSk09UJKRFW30+SxH4miDNG1CVPfoEzFyRw==
```

But that generates an error stating i can't have a double escape sequence.

Do i have to some changes to the mvc routing where i tell it to use the SPA fallback?

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });


        });
```

Somehow this seems not logical at all as angular takes care of the url by setting it to the default routing.

If someone could help me out, that would be great!

Comment: So after some more investigating in this issue if found out that routing actually works pretty well. The real problem is that the token i'm given by the .net identity service in order to change the password contains slashes for some reason, which ofcourse freaks out routing.

Comment: As a side note: why don't you pass the token in a header (authorization)? And when you use a jwt token, then you won't have to include the user-id (sub) as well.